# How to update Table records in fixed intervals in microsft Dataverse (Common data service)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, common-data-service, dataverse

I am trying MS Dataverse(CDS) for the first time. Say I have a table called "User" which has a column called "credits" which is a whole number. After every 21 days, I want to increment the value of "credits" record for all the users by 5 i;e increase the value of "credits" column for all users by 5 every 21 days.

Is there a way to automate this ?
The table can also have additional columns such as "StartDate", "CreditDate" which can be used for making calculation for 21 days.

I was looking into Rollup and Calculated column types but they don't seem like the right answer since my case has more to do with automating rather than calculation.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely this can be performed and for our developer's sake Microsoft built and provided a very nice cloud service called [Power Automate (Cloud Flows).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/)

Power automate is very powerful and can perform a lot, as it has I don't know number of connections to different system and definitely CDS is out of box

For your use case you need [flow on a scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks)

[Then you need CDS current env connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/)